# Quicktime-like video trimming in Linux?

Tags: software-rec, video-editing

One thing I loved about Quicktime 10 in Mac OS X (despite all its other shortcomings) was the ability to very easily trim a video file. I.e., I open the video in Quicktime drag two sliders to indicate the segment I want to cut from the video, then click Save As. All of this can happen very quickly.

I really want to recreate this ease in Linux (I am running the latest Fedora but would love a distro-adnostic solution), but so far the best I can do was to clip videos in OpenShot or Kdenlive. The problem there is that I need to *export* the segment resulting in re-encoding which takes much longer.

Is there a way to easily trim/clip videos in Linux? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

*Not very quicktime-like, but this is what I do:*

You can use `avconv` (Or `ffmpeg`, with a slightly different syntax than the one below), first open the file in any player, take the time at the start point, then the time at the end point, and then in a terminal:

```
avconv -ss 0:01:00 -i source.mp4 -codec:a copy -codec:v copy -t 00:02:00 a.mp4
```

For `ffmpeg`, it has to do something like this:

```
ffmpeg -ss 0:01:00 -i source.mp4 -acodec copy -vcodec copy -t 00:02:00 a.mp4
```

This will seek (`-ss hh:mm:ss`) one minute in the video, and then cut (`-t hh:mm:00`) two minutes.

The use of `-codec:a copy -codec:v` means to copy the audio and the video streams, so no re-encoding will happen.

Note that the `-ss` seeks the source, thus needs to be before `-i`, while `-t` stops writhing the output after a certain length, thus needs to be after it.